# Clipped Floating Action Button CSS

Tags: html, css, material-design

**The problem**

I'm trying to create a website using [Material Design Lite](http://www.getmdl.io), and I'm trying to insert a Floating Action Button on the top of a card. But thing is... It's getting clipped! I'm not sure why, I'm kinda new to this world.

**Expected behavior**

I want something like this. (Taken from [here](http://www.getmdl.io/templates/blog/index.html)).

[image]

**What I'm getting**

This is how my FAB looks like now.

[image]

**The code**

Here's the **HTML**.

```
<div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp card card-historico">
                    <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-shadow--4dp mdl-color--accent fab-top-right" id="refresh">
                        <i class="material-icons" role="presentation">refresh</i>
                        <span class="visuallyhidden">Refresh</span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="mdl-card__title card-title">
                        <h4 class="mdl-card__title-text">Histórico</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container">
                        <!-- Table contents here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And the **CSS**

```
.card {
   margin: 5% auto;
}

.card-title {
   background: #455A64; 
   color: #FEFEFE;
}

.card-historico {
   width: 45%;
   height: auto;
   z-index: 2;
}

.card-historico-table {
   margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

.fab-top-right {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   right: 28px;
   transform: translate(0px, -28px);
   z-index: 900;
}
```

The rest of the CSS is from MDL, so... I'm not sure if I'll have to post it here.

Anyways, can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: try enabling `overflow: visible` for  `.card-historico`.

Comment: Can you create a demo of your issue?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay `overflow: visible` solved the problem! Post it as an answer so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing a little bit of your `CSS` like:

```
.card-historico {
   width: 45%;
   height: auto;
   z-index: 2;
   overflow: visible;
}
```

this `overflow: visible` will do the trick for you. :)